# Self-Service User Sharing Rule

Tags: community, partner-portal, owd

I bought a Partner Community over a month ago and changed the account object setting to private so that our partner can only see they accounts they own.

However, when I made this change to the OWD (Organization Wide Defaults) our self-service portal super users could not see the cases within their account.

I was told by someone at Salesforce that I should use a criteria-based sharing rule to give my self-service users access to the accounts and cases within their organization...but I cannot figure out how to accomplish this.

I have been trying to get this settled for over a month and am desperate. Would greatly appreciate any help that might be out there.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ownership based Sharing Rules to share everything owned by Roles and Internal Subordinates (only appears when you have a Portal or Community Enabled) with Roles and Internal Subordinates.

This way all accounts will be visible to all internal users.